# Liferay  6.1.0 CE  web-content images not showing after upgrade from Liferay 6.0.6 CE

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, web-content

I have upgraded liferay 6.0.6 to Liferay 6.1.0 for this I already copied the document library folder before upgrade. Now after upgrade all documents are coming fine like word, pdf which is stored in document library folder.

My concern is images which are not displaying correctly. The path of images are like `DOMAIN_NAME//image/image_gallery...`

To resolve this I have changed the permission to `DLHook` in Liferay 6.0.6 and then started up-gradation for Liferay 6.1.0 CE. As per my knowledge Liferay 6.1.0 CE only supports DLHook that I have changed already.

Can anyone suggest me what I am missing here?

Comment: similar problem is posted on official site : http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14591675

Comment: @PrakashK No luck so far for this issue. In case you have any solution please update me.

Comment: Sunil I have upgradated to 6.0.6 from 5.2.3 successfully, all the contents are loading fine, images are fine but the problem is with documents it is not showing. can you please tell me the configuration you have done in 6.0.6 to get them work . Thanks

Comment: Hi Mudasar, While upgrading from Liferay 5.2.3 CE to Liferay 6.0.6 CE copy document_library folder and use "image.hook.impl=com.liferay.portal.image.DatabaseHook" and "dl.hook.impl=com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.FileSystemHook"in portal-ext.properties file (according to your system change these properties). HTH Thanks,Sunil

Comment: Hi sunil, 6.0.6 is fine but now problem is, when upgrading from liferay 6.0.6 to 6.1 Ga1 , no content , no images and no documents are shown. can you please send me you portal-ext.properties file ? so that I can see what I am missing. Thanks

Comment: Hi Mudasar, unfortunately even I am not able to solve the problem. Please share if you get any solution for the same. Thanks, Sunil

Comment: Ok sunil I will share , if I get some thing. Thanks

Comment: For contents I figured out the problem. do you have problem with contents?

Comment: I am only facing problem with images. Let me know if you find something for the same. Thanks,Sunil

Comment: I am facing the problem with images, documents and also portlets are removed from the pages :( any idea ?

Comment: Parkash or sunil , have you completed migration ? I have some issue